# Graph facebook api authentication

Tags: asp.net, facebook-graph-api

I try to post any message from `asp.net` web site using `graph-facebook-api`. I created developer app and used `appid` and `appsecret` also,  I added my web site url [localhost] in app domain. When run the site it returns the following message

```
{
   "error": {
      "message": "Can't load URL: The domain of this URL isn't included in the app's domains. To be able to load this URL, add all domains and sub-domains of your app to the App Domains field in your app settings.",
      "type": "OAuthException",
      "code": 191,
      "fbtrace_id": "Aq+jSX8OjVZ"
   }
}
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: You need to add the domain of where the app is running to the settings at [developer.facebook.com](https://https://developer.facebook.com).

Comment: i already added when creating app.

Comment: Can you share your code where you doing request to fb.

Comment: i updated question with shoots you can take a look https://stackoverflow.com/users/7931116/pavan-vora

Answer (score 0):

i solved it by setting all redirect sub domain in Facebook Login product setting as in screen shoot:
[image]